# arduino car with ultra sonic sensors

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a problem with my code. I wired everything correctly, but the values that the sensors read are either wrong. Or the code I wrote is wrong. The car never stops when something is within 20cm of the front sensor. It rather just keeps driving. The RC car is hooked up to the arduino with 3 ultrasonic sensors. And the RC motors are driven by an H-bridge(not the shield). The commented code parts are the code for if the RC car had a servo. But this car had 2 RC motors.
Here is the code:

```
 //Libraries.
//#include <Servo.h>
#include <NewPing.h>

//Variables.
/*const int pos = 103; //Servo midden 103*
  const int StrLeft = 70; //Serv0 naar links.
  const int StrRight = 133; //Servo naar rechts.*/
int Left = 5;
int Right = 4;
int Forwards = 3;
int Backwards = 2;
int potPin = A0;
int speed = 0;
#define TRIGGER_PIN1 11 //Front 
#define ECHO_PIN1 12
#define TRIGGER_PIN2 7 //Left
#define ECHO_PIN2 8
#define TRIGGER_PIN3  9 //Right
#define ECHO_PIN3 10
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200
#define MAX_DISTANCEF 1000

//Name of the objects.
//Servo MyServo;
NewPing sonar1(TRIGGER_PIN1, ECHO_PIN1, MAX_DISTANCEF);//Front
NewPing sonar2(TRIGGER_PIN2, ECHO_PIN2, MAX_DISTANCE);//Left
NewPing sonar3(TRIGGER_PIN3, ECHO_PIN3, MAX_DISTANCE);//Right

//Start of the program.
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int Fwd = false;
  /*MyServo.attach(9); //Pin number of the attached Servo.
    MyServo.write(pos); //Resets to this posistion automatically.*/
  pinMode(Left, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Right, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Forwards, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Backwards, OUTPUT);
}

//During the program.
void loop() {
  //Sturen
  /*MyServo.write(pos);
    delay(1000);
    MyServo.write(StrLeft);
    Serial.print("Links");
    delay(1000);
    MyServo.write(StrRight);
    Serial.print("Rechts");
    delay(1000);
    MyServo.write(pos);
    delay(1000);*/
  //Value of the potentiometer
  speed = analogRead(potPin);
  speed = map(speed, 0, 1023, 0, 179);
  Serial.print(speed);

  //Sensor
  unsigned int distanceF = sonar1.ping_cm();//Front
  unsigned int distanceL = sonar2.ping_cm();//Left
  unsigned int distanceR = sonar2.ping_cm();//Right
  Serial.print(distanceF);
  Serial.print(distanceL);
  Serial.print(distanceR);
  Serial.print("cm");
  delay(50);

  //Values for driving
  if (distanceF > 50 ) {
    int Fwd = true;
    Serial.print("true");
  } else {
    int Fwd = false;
    Serial.print("false");
    Stp();
  }
  delay(50);
  if ((distanceF = true) && (distanceL > distanceR)) {
    fwdLeft();
  } else if ((distanceF = true) && (distanceR > distanceL)){
    fwdRight();
  }
  delay(50);
}
void fwdLeft() {
  digitalWrite(Forwards, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Backwards, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Left, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Right, LOW);
}
void fwdRight() {
  digitalWrite(Forwards, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Backwards, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Left, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Right, HIGH);
}
void Stp() {
  digitalWrite(Forwards, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Backwards, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Left, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Right, LOW);
}
```

Comment: I guess You should (double) check(debug) distances. Make new file just to debug values from sensors. And I found mistake in Your code. `unsigned int distanceR = sonar2.ping_cm();//Right` should be `unsigned int distanceR = sonar3.ping_cm();//Right` I guess

Comment: @SilvioCro Thank you for noticing the mistake. But the problem is more that the frontal sensor doesn't change the variable Fwd into false. When something is infront of it. instead it just keeps driving

Comment: I'll write little sketch in few minutes

Comment: A H-bridge doesn't have inputs named "left", "right", "forwards" and backwards". Your pin names make no sense. And your `fwdLeft` and `fwdRight` functions are probably wrong.  You never instruct your car to go forward. Variable `Fwd ` does nothing. Why is it an `int`? Even if you stop the car, it's immediately instructed to move "left" or "right". `(distanceF = true)` makes no sense. Why are you setting `distanceF ` to true? There are too many thing wrong with this code and this site isn't a debugging service.

Comment: You should first test each thing individually, so you can make sure you know how it works, before you put it all together and wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you see in the serial output?  Does the sensor reach the expected value when the car fails to stop?  Or does the sensor show incorrect values?

Comment: Why is this off-topic?  The problem statement is perfectly clear, and the included code is minimal, complete, and verifiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you said that that `Fwd` variable never changes.  Note that you have three different variables name `Fwd`, though it seems you probably intended to have one global one.

The first is in `setup`:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int Fwd = false;
  // ...
}
```

This `Fwd` is local to setup.  It's set but never read.  Once `setup` is finished, it no longer exists.

The other two are here:

```
if (distanceF > 50 ) {
  int Fwd = true;
  Serial.print("true");
} else {
  int Fwd = false;
  Serial.print("false");
  Stp();
}
```

Each of those is a new variable that's local to the scope in which it's defined (from the definition until the closing curly brace).  Again, these are set but never inspected.

I think what you intended is to declare a global variable outside of any function:

```
int Fwd = false;
```

Then, whenever you want to change it, you'd just assign to it without repeating the type:

```
Fwd = true;
```

Then you have lines like this:

```
if ((distanceF = true) && (distanceL > distanceR))
```

I'm not sure what you intended by `(distanceF = true)`, but I don't think that code does what you think it does.  Since you used a single `=`, that's an assignment not a comparison.  So your if-condition is actually changing the value of `distanceF` to `true` rather than checking to see if it is true (or non-zero).  I suspect you wanted `Fwd` there:

```
if (Fwd && (distanceL > distanceR))
```

None of that explains why the car doesn't actually stop though.  I suspect you also have a problem reading the data from the ultrasonic sensor.  Perhaps the units aren't what is expressed in the code or you need to do some averaging (or other filtering) of the readings in order to reduce noise and faulty readings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code, you just need to adjust code for yourself, but logic Works, at least car will stop if is something in front. Also watch how you write your code. In if statment instead of `==` you have `=`
Also give proper names for variables and functions.

```
if (distanceF < 50)
{
    // Code that will stop the car
}
else
{
    // Code that will drive car forward
}

if (Fwd)
{
    if (distanceL > distanceR)
    {
        // Code that will drive car left
    }
    else
    {
        // Code that will drive car right
    }
}
```